# usage of "and" in listing items, especially in cases where it is repeated

Tags: writing-style

Please see the statement below:

> Hyphenate all compound numbers between twenty-one **and** ninety-nine, **and** fractions less than one.

In the above case, the first "and" is past of the first item in the list, whereas the second "and" indicates that what follows is a new item.

How do we indicate this difference: that one is part of a list and the other marks a new item? Do we do this with commas? If so, how? Thanks

Comment: Yes, exactly. Commas are used to make things clear. Please note that style is not grammar, that you can search the site for questions about commas, and that we have a [list of good references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online) where you might want to do further reading. You might also be interested in [ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), our sister site, which is a very good site for basic English questions.

Comment: I would also recommend hyphenating all fractions, proper or improper.

Comment: I'm intrigued about the extract. Where is it from?

Answer (score -2):

Please note that many native speakers cannot properly use "and" or commas in their writing, so don't rely on examples from classmates or coworkers.  Good Luck!  ..... Oh, and by the way, be sure to study the style variation called "serial comma" or "Oxford comma"; that is, the choice of putting a comma (or not) before the  last item in a list of three or more.  —  A, B, C and D. — or — A, B, C, and D.
The important thing about this is to learn which format is used as "house style", and then to be consistent.